# Jena SPARQL Algebra operators

Tags: sparql

Recently, when I try to use Jena to develop a stream based provenance aware sparql query engine, I confront some problems.

Does anyone know the detailed mechanism about how Jena SPARQL Algebra operators apply onto the RDF dataset? I know there is `OpExecutor` Class, but I need the detailed procedures. i.e., It seems that Jena firstly get the query Plan, and `QueryIterator`, but I can’t find where it connects the queries with the dataset. According to my understanding, it happens during the `ResultSet.nextBinding()` method. But I don’t know how? And this is only for SELECT queries, what about other types of queries?

Could anyone give me a detailed high level logic flow chart including all the relating classes?

We can also discuss it with Skype or other IM to clarify the question.

Thank you very much.

Looking forward to the replies.

Comment: I guess asking it on the mailing list is enough, isn't it? You just should wait a bit until you get the answer. This question is pretty much to tool specific, asking about the internals of Jena.

Comment: Asked here: https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/55b7247b0c547ef7561cb3d47dfe471d6ad7debd3f556b5b78282040@%3Cusers.jena.apache.org%3E